# JFileChooser keep adding extension

Tags: jfilechooser, filewriter

If I save a file like test.csv and open it, JFileChooser will see it like test.cvs. When I am going to save it again it adds csv so i'm getting test.csv.csv and so on. I know it has something to do with FileWriter because I added extension to a file like:

```
File fajl = new File (fc.getSelectedFile()+".csv");
```

Is there any way to remove extension when file is opened, and again when it is saved, i wont get test.csv.csv?

I tryed with endsWith and no luck.

This solved it for me. I used Tom van der Woerdt solution with slight modification:

```
 String s = fc.getSelectedFile().toString();
               int p = s.lastIndexOf('.');
               if(p>0){ s=s.substring(0,p);System.out.print(s);}

                 fajl = new File (s+".csv");
```

System.out.print is there just to test output name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file name has a trailing '.csv' and add it only when necessary:

```
String filePath = fc.getSelectedFile();

// add file extension if not already provided
if (!filePath.matches(".*\.csv$"))
{
  filePath += ".csv"
}

File fajl = new File(filePath);
```